# What does $a_0$ and $b_0$ represent in the indicial roots equation $r(r-1)+a_0r+b_0 = 0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What does $a_0$ and $b_0$ represent in the indicial roots equation $r(r-1)+a_0r+b_0 = 0$?
Do you plug in $0$ into $x$ of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ or do they represent the first term of the expansion? Please give a simple example if you can.

Say $$p(x) = \frac{1+x}{2}, \quad q(x) = \frac{x}{2},$$ do I plug in zero to find $a_0$ and $b_0$? So $a_0 (p(x))$ would be $1/2$ and $b_0 (q(x))$ would be $0$, or how do I find $a_0$ and $b_0$?

Thank you

Comment: What is the ODE for example?

Answer (score 2):

I assume we're solving differential equations via Frobenius method here?

If so, then the indicial equation $r(r-1)+a_0r + b_0 = 0$ arises from the differential equation

$$x^2 y^{\prime\prime} + xp(x)y + q(x)y = 0$$

where

$$p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n=a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots;\qquad q(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n = b_0 + b_1x+b_2x^2+\ldots\quad$$

From this, you can easily see that $p(0) = a_0$ and $q(0)=b_0$.